# How do I force flash bios to different model?

Tags: bios

okay, so I actually have ASUS G550JX. It was bricked for completely unknown and unrelated case, so I brought that thing to service center, which quoted $1k for replacement motherboard. What?

then, I brought that thing to the 3rd party service center, which revived my laptop. But after that, my GTX 950m stops working, my keyboard backlight stops working, and the LOGO changed to ASUS logo instead of ROG logo.

I was trying to mess with WinFlash, when I realized the laptop was running N550JV BIOS, while mine actually G550JX. How can I force reinstall the G550JX BIOS?

The same question was asked on [bios-mods.com](https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-How-do-I-force-flash-bios-to-different-model), and asked before at Server Fault, but I deleted it because I just realized I asked it on the wrong place.

Comment: Take it back to the 3rd party service center and ask if they will flash the correct bios, I assume they guarantee their work.

Comment: How was the laptop "revived"? If they replaced the board with one from N550JV then the firmware ("BIOS", actually UEFI) is correct. Ask them what was really done.

Comment: Google "force flash ASUS G550JX" I got answers right at the top of search results.

Comment: @Moab they just said "it doesnt work that way". They also given up.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I matched the current serial number on the BIOS and on the box. Perfect match. Also $50 for motherboard replacement with GTX 950m on it doesnt make sense.

Comment: @Moab I dont get anything as an answer on google. Just this thread, and my other thread at server fault which was deleted. Please link that here if possible.

Comment: I would guess they flashed the wrong BIOS. The latest one is found [here](https://www.asus.com/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-G550JX/HelpDesk_BIOS/) - Version 204. Is that your version?

Comment: @harrymc I got version 208, the N550JV latest BIOS.

Comment: Where did they get a version 208 when the latest ROG version is 204?

Comment: The version 208 was N550JV BIOS. Even systeminfo returns my laptop is now N550JV but with G550JX serial number. But actually the G550JX 204 was built around 2015, while the N550JV 208 was built around 2013.

Comment: Don't ask me what kind of black magic voodoo did they do here. :( @harrymc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer : I can't. At least using the official tools (EzFlash, WinFlash).

The longer answer : Basically, I can flash using Intel ME System Tools, after disabling the write protection first using GRUB shell. The variable differs for each laptop, so there is no general solution. Also, flashing the modded BIOS using Intel ME System Tools doesn't guarantee success flashing. I killed my ASUS ROG G550JX.

Then I revived it by using CH341 programmer, and SOIC8 test clip to program the chip directly, without desoldering. Again, this differs for every laptop, but most (if not all ASUS laptop) uses Winbond chip. [This thread on bios-mods.com](https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-How-do-I-force-flash-bios-to-different-model) that I made, only talks about my laptop. Again, there is no general solution.

The BIOS files that are provided by ASUS download link, the one that backed up using Intel ME System Tools, and the one backed up using programmer, are different. They can be used to build "other BIOS", but I don't even fully understand what does [this user on bios-mods.com](https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/User-Lost-N-BIOS) do, I only supplied him files and he gave me the dump to flash back to the BIOS chip.

N550JV and G550JX looks like a same board, but on different revision number. I also don't fully understand why N550JV BIOS boots on my G550JX, but with broken GPU. The only possible explanation are, the BIOS chip also contains the vBIOS for the NVIDIA GTX 950m, but N550JV uses GT 750m, thus making conflict.

TL;DR : I also don't understand what did he do.

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion from the information that you supplied is that the
repair center has
replaced the ROG BIOS, whose last version for the G550JX was
[version 204](https://www.asus.com/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-G550JX/HelpDesk_BIOS/),
with the ASUS BIOS for the N550JV, whose last version was
[version 208](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/N550JV/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

This explains the hardware problems that this update has introduced.
You should really ask for the refund of the $50 that you paid,
and never go there again.

I describe below how to return the correct BIOS 204, but note that this may
not fix any other problem that may have caused the laptop to be bricked in
the first place, and might be dangerous by itself.

**Installing from within the BIOS**

- Note well all your BIOS settings, even take pictures of all the BIOS screens
- Download BIOS
  [version 204](https://www.asus.com/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-G550JX/HelpDesk_BIOS/)
  and store on a USB device.
- Boot to BIOS
- Navigate to *Tool*, then *EZ Flash*
- Select the USB device, then the file and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- At the prompt, review one final time and accept
- Reboot upon completion
- Check the BIOS version again to ensure the update was applied.
  You will need to re-apply any BIOS settings manually.

**Installing using ASUS WinFlash**

This process is described in more detail in the ASUS article
[Update BIOS-How to update the BIOS version in Windows system?](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1008276/)

- Download and unzip the appropriate version (32 or 64) of
  [ASUS WinFlash](https://asus-winflash.en.lo4d.com/windows)
- Install and start WinFlash
- Click *Get BIOS from Device*
- Point to the BIOS file
- On the screen that compares the current and new BIOS, verify the data
- Click *Update*
- Wait for 2~3 minutes until the BIOS update process is completed
- Click *Exit* for auto-reboot and continue the BIOS update process
- Verify the BIOS version

Comment: but the laptop is revived from completely bricked situation ... so asking them to refund is just unfair. also all the steps you mentioned above will reject the G550JX BIOS file, said "this file is for other laptop" or some variation like that.

Comment: Try from a Command Prompt to run WinFlash with parameters. I know of the  `/nodate` parameter, but that might not be it. There may be a `/force` parameter. If not, try to find another parameter by running WinFlash with an intentional parameter error or with `/?`.

Comment: `nodate` and `force` doesn't work. I'll try to look for another way. thanks

Comment: There are methods to force the BIOS installation, but they had better be done by the service center. You could return there and demand that they install the right BIOS. Installing a wrong BIOS is an error, after all.